# Error in Management Reporter 2012 when you publish a report to SharePoint: "Unable to create the related report link"

Tags: 2013, reports

Solutions tried so far:

---

A common cause of this error is that the service account running the Management Reporter Process Service does not have the Design permission on the SharePoint library

---

Remove the invalid characters from the report's Output name per the SharePoint requirements

---

Under Document Library Settings and Advanced Settings set "Allow Management of Content Types" from no to yes

---

Under Content Types in your Document Library Settings page click on "Add from Existing Content Types" and add the "Link to Document" content type

---

Security Configuration section, click Blocked file types from Central admin link, and Remove the "Url" type in the list (Only if exists)

---

Install Desktop experience services, restarted machine and tried to publish the report link. Also checked running services like Computer browser and WebClient and its running fine.

---

Still its giving me error says: Unable to create the related report link. Any help appreciated very much.

Thanks,
Bhavin

Answer (score 1):

go to the SQL server MR uses, launch MR configuration console, check Management Report Process Service, the service account has to have Designer permission in that SP library.